# Question about the Chinese Remainder Theorem and the residue class ring ${\bf Z}/p\# {\bf Z}$

Tags: ring-theory, prime-numbers, chinese-remainder-theorem, reduced-residue-system

In a question that I asked on MO, Terence Tao [observed](https://mathoverflow.net/a/203928/15915) that:

> The Chinese Remainder Theorem tells us that the residue class ring
>    ${\bf Z}/p\# {\bf Z}$ is isomorphic (as a ring) to the product of of
>   the finite fields ${\bf Z}/q {\bf Z}$ where $q$ ranges over the primes
>   up to $p$.

Can someone explain how the Chinese Reminder Theorem can be used to show this isomorphism?

Comment: We have a canonical ring homomorphism $\mathbb Z/p\#\mathbb Z \to \prod_{q \leq p} \mathbb Z/q\mathbb Z$, by reducing modulo $q$ for each $q$. The CRT says precisely that it is bijective. You can look this up probably in every article "ever" written about the CRT, e.g. Wikipedia.

Comment: Thanks @Engloutie.  I looked up CRT on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem) and didn't see the details that you mentioned.  Which section would it be in?

Comment: At the end of "Theorem Statement". Of course, the above is only a special case, where all exponents are $1$.